# How to overcome: 'v-slot' directive must be owned by a custom element, but 'slot' is not.eslint-plugin-vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have Vue.js app and the key part of the code of component looks as following:

`specific-modal.vue:`

```
<template>
  <v-modal-dialog
    :visible="isModalVisible"
    title="CONNECTION"
    okText="Save"
    cancelText="Cancel"
    :isSaveDisabled="isDisabled"
    :width="550"
    :height="620"
    @ok="onOk"
    @cancel="onCancel"
    @hiding="onHiding"
  >
    ...
```

`base-modal.vue:`

```
<template>
  <DxPopup
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :hide-on-outside-click="true"
    :drag-enabled="true"
    :wrapper-attr="popupAttributes"
    position="center"
    v-on="$listeners"
    @hiding="onHiding"
  >
    <slot />
    <slot name="footer">
      <DxToolbarItem template="save-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
      <template #save-template>
        <DxButton text="Ok" @click="onOk" />
      </template>

      <DxToolbarItem template="cancel-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
      <template #cancel-template>
        <DxButton text="Cancel" @click="onCancel" />
      </template>
    </slot>
  </DxPopup>
</template>

<script>
import { DxPopup, DxToolbarItem } from "devextreme-vue/popup";
import DxButton from 'devextreme-vue/button';
...
```

The `#save-template` is underlined with red line and there is a message:

`'v-slot' directive must be owned by a custom element, but 'slot' is not.eslint-plugin-vue`

How to overcome this isssue?

`EDIT:`

If I do as following:

```
<slot />
<slot name="footer">
  <DxToolbarItem template="save-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
  <custom-element>
    <template #save-template>
      <DxButton text="TEST" @click="onOk" />
    </template>
  </custom-element>

  <DxToolbarItem template="cancel-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
  <custom-element>
    <template #cancel-template>
      <DxButton text="Cancel" @click="onCancel" />
    </template>
  </custom-element>
</slot>
```

When I run the app, I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <custom-element> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

`<template #save-template` is a shorthand for `<template v-slot='save-template'`.

So the eslint rule is complaining that the `<template v-slot='save-template'` is owned (has a parent) that is not a custom element (which is ).

`<slot>` is a like a placeholder that external components can use to add data. But in your code it seems like you are saying a placeholder has provided a placeholder inside it.

To overcome this either change parent slot tag to something else. Or, wrap template tag in a tag like:

```
<template>
    <DxPopup
        v-bind="$attrs"
        :hide-on-outside-click="true"
        :drag-enabled="true"
        :wrapper-attr="popupAttributes"
        position="center"
        v-on="$listeners"
        @hiding="onHiding"
    >
        <slot />

        <slot name="footer">
            <DxToolbarItem template="save-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />

            <!-- Add custom element wrapping here -->
            <custom-element>
                <template #save-template>
                    <DxButton text="TEST" @click="onOk" />
                </template>
            </custom-element>
        </slot>
    </DxPopup>
</template>
```

More details:

- https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/valid-v-slot.html
- https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#named-slots

Comment: Thank you. But, I'm not sure how to do it. Please, take a look at EDIT part in the original post.

Comment: `<custom-element>` is just a random name. You need to create your own. A custom element is anything that is not a regular html element (div, span, li .. etc). For example, in your code DxPopup is a custom element.

Comment: I wrote <DxPopup> instead of <custom-element>. There is no erros this time, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to archive. If you just want to display a button, then remove both parent elements (`<custom-element>` and `<template>`) and keep `<DxButton>`.

Comment: Yes, I just want to display those 2 buttons. And it works in that way without <custom-element> and <template>, but I need to use DxToolbarItem as footer layout container.

Comment: So why not use DXToolbarItem like the the sibling element?

Comment: What do you mean sibling item?

Comment: You have another DxToolbarItem element in your code. You can add as many DxToolbarItem as you want. Check vue example here:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/Popup/Customize_the_Appearance/Specify_Toolbar_Items/

Comment: The issue with that appraoach is in what to do if I decide to use my own custom button, not standard `widget="dxButton"`? I want to use `<CustomButton>` instead of `<DxButton>`. We make our own component library that wraps DevExtreme components.

Comment: Then use the answer that I posted. Replace `<custom-element>` with `<CustomButton>` :)

Comment: The `<CustomButton>` should be placed inside template. That's how it works in DevExtreme.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution on `Stackoverflow`:

```
<template>
  <DxPopup
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :hide-on-outside-click="true"
    :drag-enabled="true"
    :wrapper-attr="popupAttributes"
    position="center"
    v-on="$listeners"
    @hiding="onHiding"
  >
    <slot />
    <slot name="footer">
      <DxToolbarItem template="save-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
      <DxToolbarItem template="cancel-template" toolbar="bottom" location="after" />
    </slot>

    <template #save-template>
      <DxButton text="TEST" @click="onOk" />
    </template>
    <template #cancel-template>
      <DxButton text="Cancel" @click="onCancel" />
    </template>
  </DxPopup>
</template>
```